# Event-Sourcing: Aggregate Roots and Performance

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing, aggregateroot

I'm building a StackOverflow clone using event-sourcing.  The MVP is simple:

1. Users can post a question
2. Users can answer a question
3. Users can upvote and downvote answers to non-closed questions

I've modeled the question as the aggregate root.  A question can have zero or more answers and an answer can have zero or more upvotes and downvotes.

This leads to a massive performance problem, though.  To upvote an answer, the question (being the aggregate root) must be loaded which requires loading all of its answers.  In non-event-sourced DDD, I would use lazy loading to solve this problem.  But lazy loading in event-sourcing is non-trivial (http://docs.geteventstore.com/introduction/event-sourcing-basics/)

Is it correct to model the question as the aggregate root?

Comment: Vernon seems to suggest that these should be multiple aggregates to avoid concurrency issues: http://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/images/9780321834577/samplepages/0321834577.pdf

Comment: No, you didn't model an aggregate root. You 'modeled' a data structure/view model and called it 'aggregate root'. Proper DDD doesn't have this problem and this is one of the most common DDD mistakes. Your model is simply wrong, you need to try again to do identify the aggregates and their consistency rules. Btw, usually CQRS is the answer for performance, but in this case, the model is still wrong regardless of cqrs.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I found this example by Vaughn Vernon which was immensely helpful:  https://github.com/VaughnVernon/IDDD_Samples/tree/05d95572f2ad6b85357b216d7d617b27359a360d/iddd_collaboration/src/main

Comment: You might want to use snapshots instead of lazy loading. http://cqrs.nu/Faq/event-sourcing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly don't use lazy loading (while using ORM). You may find yourself in even worse situation, because of that, than waiting a little bit longer. If you need to use it, most of the times it means, that your model is just simply wrong.

You probably want to think about things like below:

1. How many answers to the question you expect.
2. What happens, if someone posted an answer while you were submiting yours. The same about upvotes.
3. Does upvote is just simply +1 and you don't care about it anymore or you can find all upvotes for user and for example change them to downvote (upvotes are identified).

You probably want to go for separate aggregates, not because of performance problems, but because of concurrency problems (question 2).

According to performance and the way your upvote behave you may think about modeling it as value object. (question 3)

Go ahead and `read it` http://dddcommunity.org/library/vernon_2011/

True performance hit you may achieve by using cqrs read/write separation
http://udidahan.com/2009/12/09/clarified-cqrs/

Comment: Thanks for the Vernon tip.  His book has been very illuminating and examples on GitHub have been an enormous help.

Answer (score 0):

With a simple read model it should not be a problem. What is the maximum number of answer you would expect for a question? Maybe a few hundred which is not a big deal with a denormalized data model.

The upvote event would be triggered by a very simple command with a handful of properties.

The event handler would most likely have to load the whole question. But it is very quick to load those records by the aggregate root ID and replay the events. If the number of events per question gets very high (due to answer edits, etc) you can implement snapshots instead of replaying every single event. And that process is done asynchronously which will make the read model "eventually consistent" with the event store.